# How do I create an array from a grouping of row_number()?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have code that uses row_number() partitioned by date. I would like to create an array that contains data grouped by the row_number that is partitioned by date.

example code is something like this:

```
w=Window.partitionBy('part_id', 'part_date').orderBy(col('timestamp').desc())
df2 =df.withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(w))
```

The above code works for creating the partition. I am not sure how to create the array grouped by date that yields the part_num.

I thought maybe something like this. (this code does not work, just an example)

```
.withColumn('array_prt_num' , array('part_num')).groupBy('row_num')
```

thoughts?

Image link to df output wish

[image]

Comment: *that yields the part_num*? which part_num

Comment: actually the last bit of code it does not work at all. it was more of a rough example.

Comment: can you provide a sample of df2? i am sure that you can group it there. But group by row_number 1 so what shpould be the result an bunch iog poart_num as json?

Comment: Image link to df output wish -> https://ibb.co/JRxCb8x

Comment: you question is miss leading you want a group by 'part_id', 'part_date' and not by row_num and please never post images of data, when someone will test their algorithm they need data